# Two inline tables without line break

Tags: css, asp.net, html, view

I have a view where two tables have to be visually combined in one. First table has 1 row, Second has multiple rows. The trouble is that after displaying first table (width:~3000px, with all tds) line breaks, and second one is displayed on new line, not inline.

My code looks like:

```
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <table>
        <tr>
        //a lot of td 
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        //and so on
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you don't set a width, the tables will take as much room as they need.  If both can't fit on one row, they won't be on one row.

Comment: can u send me demo link or code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code and comments below.

```css
section {
  font-size: 0; /* avoid whitespace between inline-block children */
  white-space: nowrap; /* prevent wrapping to new line */
}
section div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px; /* re-set font-size here to whatever you need */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/3000/200" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: mb you could also help me with setting height to first div inside Section. So as I want two tables first lines to be at same level, div has to inherit height and then set its top position. Setting height:100%; or inherit to div does not help.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: there is a limit 90 mins

Comment: Too sad, but you'll have to wait then. Questions should not be extended/altered in nature when already answered, and comments are not for asking new questions, even if they are related.